# FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED doesn't always work

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to display my application over the lock screen on android.

I have it working some of the time. But certain scenarios will not work.

I am starting my activity which extends a React Native Activity from a service like so:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

And I am setting the flags on the window like this in the `onCreate` method:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

## When it works:

If the activity has been started when the device is unlocked and the app is still in recents. The device will wake and the activity will be displayed over the lock screen.

Activity state changes witnessed:

- onRestarted
- onStarted
- onResumed
- onPaused
- onResumed

## When it doesn't work:

If the app hasn't been run since boot or the app has been removed from the recents. The device will sometimes wake and sometimes the app will flash for a second before returning to the lock screen. When the device is unlocked the app is running.

Activity state changes witnessed:

- onCreated
- onStarted
- onResumed
- onPaused
- onStopped

I'm not sure if this is specific to React Native or not.

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem. Do you have by any chance an explanation of this problem?

Comment: @Bazouk55555 I never found a solution for this and have not touched this issue in a long time